# SpannableStringBuilder chinese

Tags: java

when use SpannableStringBuilder append data,If a data contains both Chinese and English or digital, the default will be the Chinese and other segmentation, don't know why.
for example a name 王贺2 ，it will be 王贺 and 2.

log show one is 李贺 ，other is 2  。。so  I do not know  why.

Comment: Could you provide code sample? What log? You mean output in IDE window?

Comment: SpannableStringBuilder spanner = new SpannableStringBuilder();EmailAddressSpan span = new EmailAddressSpan(address, i == (mAddressList.size() - 1));
            start = spanner.length();
            spanner.append("李刚3");
            spanner.setSpan(span, start, spanner.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
code：

Comment: code: EmailAddressSpan draw method 
@Override
        public void draw(final Canvas canvas, final CharSequence text,
                         final int start, final int end,
                         final float x, final int top, final int y, final int bottom,
                         final Paint paint) {
            if (LOGD) Log.d(TAG, "draw: " + text.toString().subSequence(start, end) + ", at bottom: " + bottom);

log out 李刚 and 3 ，it is just chinese and others。